# How to connect informix DB using C language

Tags: c, informix

Please help me to connect informix db using c language. I googled, but I couldn't find correct way. Is ESQL/C solution for that? I have no any idea about ESQL/C. If you have any idea about connecting to the informix db using c language in anyway, as soon as possible tell me.

Comment: There's a C edition on [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/informix/downloads.html) page, is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the easiest ways of connecting do Informix database from C language is connecting via ODBC interface. You will find many tutorials on how to do it from C language. There is even open source [`unixODBC`](http://www.unixodbc.org/) with `isql` console application. Using this application written in C I can connect to Informix database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ESQL/C is the solution for connection to informix with c. 
If you are on Unix side you can find demo files in $INFORMIXDIR/demo/esqlc directory.
If you are on Windows side you can Download the IBM Informix SDK which includes also demo Files.

See also [Informix Guide to ESQL/C](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.esqlc.doc/esqlc.htm?lang=en)